# Return Value from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, shell, variables, plsql

So, we have a shell script, which needs to call an anonymous block, and receive a value back.   The anonymous block is about 100 lines, so we have it in a file, hence for SQL*Plus it is called:

`@/directory_path/anonymous_block "'param1'" "'param2'"`

Yes, we pass a couple of parameters.   And at the end of this, we have a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE.......`

So, the question we have, is how to get that back to Shell?   We've tried various types of code similar to this:

```
proc=TEMPLATE1_MV<BR>
code=513

x=`print "
  set heading off feedback off verify off timing off
  @/u01/sql/stock_rpt_stats '$code' '$proc';
  exit" | sqlplus -s $user/$pass`

y=`echo $x | awk '{print $1}'`<BR>
printf "HERE: $y\n"
```

But no luck, just errors.

If this contains just a straight SQL:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) FROM dual;
```

That will work fine, but not referencing a file containing the SQL.

Anyone with some ideas would be great.   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` ?

I generally prefer to run `sqlplus` using the heredoc method and passing the result of the block to a variable like this and it works fine for me.

```
scripts-$cat ./sqlplus_exec.sh
#!/bin/bash
output=$(sqlplus -s  $user/$pass <<INP
set heading off feedback off verify off timing off
set serveroutput on
@print_output.sql
INP
)

echo "$output"
```

Here's the SQL file

```
scripts-$cat print_output.sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO WORLD');
END;
/

scripts-$./sqlplus_exec.sh
HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: Awesome.   Works fine.  Couple tweaks to fit our setup.   Many thanks.   I'm not sure how the shell interprets my original syntax with yours, but yours works.   Thanks again.